# Can bash's ctrl-x e be initialised from standard input?

Tags: command-line, bash

There is a feature in bash I use frequently, where pressing `C-x e` will open the current command prompt in `$EDITOR`, and on closing the buffer will execute the written command.

There is a related command, `fc`, which takes its input from the bash history. The [manual](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1p-fc/) suggests it does not use standard input at all.

I would like a command `cmd` such that something like: `echo "ls" | cmd` would open up a buffer containing `ls`, and on the write of that buffer, execute the given command (just like either of the above). Is there an existing command with this property?

Answer (score 0):

This trick works in my Debian 9:

```
echo "ls" | vipe | . /dev/stdin
```

[`vipe`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vipe) allows you to run your editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and edit the data that is being piped between programs. It's from the `moreutils` package. It respects the `EDITOR` variable.

There are at least two issues:

1. In the above command `.` acts in a subshell. You can place e.g. `foo=bar` in the buffer and execute it but it won't affect your current shell. Even if we craft `cmd` (say, as a shell function) so `.` in it acts in the shell interpreting `cmd`, you will still use it like `echo "ls" | cmd`, so the entire `cmd` won't act in your current shell.

   If this issue is a problem for you, research `shopt -o lastpipe` and `set +m`, experiment with them.
2. Commands will see their stdin coming from the pipe. My tests indicate `.` reads the entire file (stream in our case) before interpreting anything. Commands you want to run will not consume parts of the stream because when they start, the pipe is already closed by `vipe`.

   In this context `.` is safe but `bash` is not (at least GNU Bash 4.4.12 in my Debian 9). Compare these two:

   ```
   yes cat | head -n 100 | . /dev/stdin    # cats die silently
   yes cat | head -n 100 | bash            # the first cat catches later cats
   ```

   So with `.` the commands will not consume the pipe; this is good. But some commands may find the closed pipe unacceptable. Example:

   ```
   $ echo "top" | vipe | . /dev/stdin    # change nothing and exit the editor
   top: failed tty get
   ```

   The following function tries to deal with the problem:

   ```
   cmd() { </dev/tty . <(vipe); }
   ```

   Now if you call `echo "top" | cmd` then `vipe` will read from the pipe, yet commands you accept in the buffer will use `/dev/tty` as their stdin.

   Note `vipe` itself (after saving its input stream to a file) manipulates its descriptors, opens `/dev/tty` and spawns the editor that uses `/dev/tty` instead of the (`vipe`'s) original stdin and stdout. Still there is no risk of reading from `/dev/tty` concurrently because the editor must exit before `vipe` sends anything to its (original) stdout. The tool is a Perl script, read it and see for yourself.

---

Maybe your usage case doesn't necessarily require a pipe. Maybe you can put `.` in the current shell. Examples:

```
# initial commands taken from a file (template)
. <(</the/file vipe)
```

```
# initial commands generated by some program
. <(code_generator | vipe)
```

```
# initial commands provided as here document
. <(vipe <<EOF 
ls
foo=baz
EOF
)
```

Not only these snippets can affect the current shell (e.g. set `foo`). They do not suffer from redirecting input (e.g. `top` doesn't complain).

The first two snippets can be turned into functions. You would provide a path (to a template or to a generator respectively, or maybe a whole shell command) as an argument. An example function based on the first snippet:

```
template() { . <(<"$1" vipe); }
```

Now you can e.g. re-source your `~/.bashrc` (strictly: a copy of it) with custom modifications without actually modifying the original file. Like this:

```
template ~/.bashrc
```

---

Note `vipe` will print the temporary file to its stdout, unless you kill it or the editor reports an error (i.e. non-zero exit status). Exiting the editor without saving the file is not enough to abort; in such case the original file will be piped further. If you don't want to execute anything then delete every command from the file and save it, so it runs nothing when sourced; or make your editor report failure (e.g. `:cq` in `vi`).